# HTML Canvas, laggy and clunky

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, browser, html5-canvas

I have 4 canvases one on top of another, every single one is 64x128px. I am stacking them because I want to mimic small horizontal LCD screen and the functionality of it. My problem is that it's getting laggy and clunky, I have 2 animations running at the same time with 100ms reload time. Is there something I could do to fix that or I am just trying to do to much in a browser?

Basically I have interval and every 100ms I am clearing canvas and drawing again.

Comment: Who'd know, it's hard to say anything about code you can't see ...

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to be refreshing it every 100ms? You want to only be redrawing the canvas when you need to for maximum efficiency.

For example, you might only want to have one canvas that is wiped and redrawn every 100ms, and only the things that you want to redraw every 100ms should be drawn on that canvas. If there's something that only changes due to user interaction, put that on a different canvas and only redraw that canvas when the user interacts with it (e.g: clicks).

The animation might also seem laggy because you're only redrawing it every 100ms. That's only 10 times per second (10fps) - maybe you should look into using [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). It's hard to know when you haven't shared your code.

Comment: ... + a thousand other reasons, please don't speculate in answers.

Comment: thanks for response, that's what I am doing. What would be your solution to clear 4 canvases at the same time? I need to do that after user presses a button and then start another animation without delay. I am using clearRect and I think that might be the reason of laggs. I will also try requestAnimationFrame().

Comment: @Teemu sorry, I wasn't aware you're not meant to do that. I was trying to help the OP with what information they gave

Comment: I wouldn't have thought clearRect() would lag the canvas, even if running it four times at once. I can't really comment on it without seeing your code, sorry.